# Styling Issues with <legend> tag in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I developed a form and I found this styling issue. When I open the form in Firefox it looks great.

When I open it in Internet Explorer `<legend>Employee details</legend>` is striking through the employee details. How can I style it to look the same as it does in Firefox (Not striking through the text)?

Comment: What version of browsers and show more code plz

Comment: Hi @SmilingLily.  Welcome to SO.  When asking for help about a specific bit of code, it is best to include the code in the question (in this case, the HTML and CSS).  Also, if any of the answers to your previous questions worked for you, you should click the checkmark beside the answer... it lets others know the question is answered and it rewards the person who helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
legend {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

in your CSS?